# How to get the URL when download button is pushed in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I want to get the URL after clicking "Download" button in CasperJS.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return Support.DownloadContent('', 'content','contents');">Download</a>
```

Comment: What is the current behaviour of this button? You didn't make it clear enought, I guess it downloads a file? Can you provide link to page?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use [`click()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#click) followed by [`getCurrentUrl()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getcurrenturl):**

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://example.com/');

casper.then(function () {
  this.click('a');
});

casper.then(function () {
  this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
});

casper.run();
```